# using comparing function

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, overloading

I have this function

```
std::vector <std::vector <int> > puddles;
std::set <int> is_checked;

size_t M, N;

bool v_compare(int a, int b){
    return puddles[(a-a%M)/M][a%M] < puddles[(b-b%M)/M][b%M];
}
```

and I want to find the set element which corresponds to the minimal value in `puddles` (I use `i*M+j` as a key in the set). So I am trying to use my function as a predicate for `min_element`

```
close(*std::min_element(is_checked.begin(), is_checked.end(), v_compare));
```

but I got this error

```
:113:82: error: no matching function for call to 'min_element(std::set<int>::iterator, std::set<int>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
:113:82: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6173:5: note: template<class _FIter> _FIter std::min_element(_FIter, _FIter)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6201:5: note: _FIter std::min_element(_FIter, _FIter, _Compare) [with _FIter = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, _Compare = bool (TFlood::*)(int, int)]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6201:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'bool (TFlood::*)(int, int)'
```

Comment: Is `v_compare` by any chance a member of a class?  Is its declaration in the class marked `static`?

Comment: yes, it's class member. i've tried to make it static, but i've got this error :18:12: error: invalid use of member 'TFlood::M' in static member function
:21:63: error: from this location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between a pointer to function and a pointer to member function.  A class member which is not `static` gets you a pointer to member function.  But `std::min_element` only accepts a pointer to function or other callable type, and a pointer to member function doesn't qualify since it can't be called without a pointer or reference to a class object.  And as you found, if you try making the function a `static` member, then it can't get at the member `M`.  (Maybe `puddles` too, if that's also a member.)

It looks like you're using g++ 4.6, which supports lambdas.  So the easiest solution is:

```
close(*std::min_element(is_checked.begin(), is_checked.end(),
      [this](int a, int b) { return puddles[a/M][a%M] < puddles[b/M][b%M]; }));
```

(I got rid of the subtractions, since division of integer types always rounds toward zero, so `(a-(a%M))/M` is always the same result as `a/M`.)  Make sure you use the `-std=c++0x` compiler flag.  The lambda magic takes care of "capturing" the `this` pointer for later use by the comparison object.

Comment: This is Standard code, and most recent compilers will handle it the same way.  It's just that it didn't become officially standardized until late 2011, so some older compilers won't.  If you need to use old compilers for some reason, you can tag a question [c++03].

Comment: ok, but there is still the same problem :129:82: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
:129:83: error: no matching function for call to 'min_element(std::set<int>::iterator, std::set<int>::iterator, TFlood::resolve()::<lambda(int, int)>)'
./tbricks_3.cpp:129:83: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6173:5: note: template<class _FIter> _FIter std::min_element(_FIter, _FIter)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6201:5: note: template<class _FIter, class _Compare> _FIter std::min_element(_FIter, _FIter, _Compare)

Comment: Did you add `-std=c++0x` to your compile command (possibly via Makefile)?